# Can't read config files from pgAdminIII on local Kubuntu machine

Tags: configuration, postgresql-9.4

My database starts fine, I can connect to it from pgAdmin and run queries.  However when I go to Tools->Server Configuration->postgresql.conf I get an error.  The error states

```
could not stat file "postgresql.conf": No such file or directory
CONTEXT: SQL function "pg_file_length" statement 1.
STATEMENT: SELECT pg_file_read('postgresql.conf', 0, pg_file_length('postgresql.conf'))
```

I tried to run that statement as its own query and came up with no such function.  I googled around and found that I need adminpack so I installed that.  Now when I run the same query I get `could not open file "postgresql.conf" for reading: No such file or directory.

The file does indeed exist at /etc/postgresql/9.4/main/ so I put the full path in the command and it tells me that absolute paths aren't allowed.  I made a symlink in my data directory `/var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main` of the postgresql.conf file.  Doing that allows me to open postgresql.conf from pgamin.  However, when I save the file I notice that I get a new postgresql.conf in my data directory and that it renames the symlink to postgresql.conf.bak which means when I have conflicting postgresql.conf files between the /etc/.../main and the /var/.../main directories.

One thought is to move all the .conf files from the /etc/ directory to the /var/ and then put symlinks in the /etc/ but I figure I should just ask rather than screw around.

Comment: I've solved it for postgresql.conf but not pg_hba.conf, I just symlinked the postgresql.conf to the correct location for PGAdmin

Comment: @Jamesking56 I just gave up and edit it in nano

Answer (score -1):

`pg_hba` and `postgresql.conf` should stay under

```
/etc/postgresql/[pg_version]/main/
```

then you should link them to `/var/lib..` with:

```
#:ln -s /etc/postgresql/[pg_version]/main/pg_hba.conf
/var/lib/postgresql/[pg_version]/main/pg_hba.conf
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. This is exactly what the asker is doing.